# Using Random.Range not working correctly in Unity3d

Tags: c#, random, unity-game-engine, scripting

I want to create a random number and I use the `Random.Range` method. But when I am calling `Random.Range` it gives me an odd number, and I call again it gives me an even number:

```
//example
calling random.range =1
calling random.range =4
calling random.range =17
calling random.range =2
calling random.range =3
```

One odd number one even number but I dont want this I want:

```
//example
calling random.range =1
calling random.range =5
calling random.range =4
calling random.range =7
calling random.range =6
calling random.range =12
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

It is an interesting behavior. I tried to reproduce it, but I couldn't - maybe it is happening only in a specific range, what random range are you using?

Anyway, you do not have to use unity random range, you can use for example:

```
public static class MyRandom {
    static System.Random rnd = new System.Random();

    public static int Range(int min, int max) {
        return min + rnd.Next() % (max + 1);
    }
}
```

And then use `MyRandom.Range(0, 10)`

Answer (score -1):

Try random.rangeMin or random.rangeMin()

Comment: i can't use that 
Error:        `UnityEngine.Random' does not contain a definition for `rangeMin'